# libcurl4 not usable during ccminer build configure

Tags: ubuntu, curl, libcurl, configure, mining

I'm trying to build ccminer from source, but whenever I do ./configure I run into the following error:

checking for curl-config... /opt/anaconda3/bin/curl-config

checking for the version of libcurl... 7.55.1

checking for libcurl >= version 7.15.2... yes

checking whether libcurl is usable... no

configure: error: Missing required libcurl >= 7.15.2

libcurl 7.55 is clearly detected, and I've tried both:
apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev
and
apt install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
so I should have the header files

do you think the problem might have something to do with the fact that it's checking in the anaconda3 directory for the config file?

Answer (score 3):

I also had this issue, the quick and dirty solution is to remove libcurl from anaconda.

```
conda remove curl
```

Answer (score 0):

An additional solution, that is not quite as dirty, is to move the reference to the anaconda bin in your PATH environment variable from the beginning to the end.

Typing $PATH into your console should print your PATH environment variable:

```
$PATH
bash: /media/user/Data/Python/anaconda3/bin:/home/user/bin:
```

To move it to the end:

```
PATH='/home/user/bin:/media/user/Data/Python/anaconda3/bin:'
```

Try running ./configure again and it should succeed.

I would also recommend saving the contents of the PATH to a text file before you mess with it just in case you mess something up and need to revert.